# fill static property from async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I want to fill this list of MyModel with async method. 
The async method returns List of MyModel.

I want to call MyClass.list in other functions.

Code :

```
 public static class MyClass
    {
       public static List<MyModel> list= await MyHelper.GetCache();
```

I'm getting an error :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1992  The 'await' operator can only be used when contained
>   within a method or lambda expression marked with the 'async' modifier

Any idea ?

Comment: don't. just block. doing `await` on the class initialization is wrong.

Comment: you should put it inside async method

Comment: @DavidHaim can you give any advice how to do this ?

Comment: @BobSwager I guess `GetCache` returns a `Task<List<MyModel>>` , so in this case simply `public static ... = MyHelper.GetCache().Result;`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is a `static` field, not a property. Static fields are evil, especially if they hold a lot of data. Redesign your architecture.

Comment: @dymanoid What do you suggest me to use to hold "cache" for my application instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use await in a static initializer like that. But you can block and wait for the result

```
public static class MyClass
    {
       public static List<MyModel> list= MyHelper.GetCache().Wait()
```

Comment: I solved my problem but i accepted your answer. I don't know if that's ok ? :)

Comment: Blocking in this way is not ok in desktop or asp.net applications. It will end with deadlock

Comment: @Fabio thank you for your comment. What's the best practice to use for handling this scenario ?

Comment: You would have to make all access to the variable async. However I'm not you will end up in a deadlock in this situation. It depends if GetCache awaits something on the main thread. It's certainly possible to deadlock and genrally best to avoid using wait.  However until c# 8 it is also not possible to declare main as async so sometimes you just have to use wait.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your environment using `.Wait()` will possible cause a deadlock (Desktop or ASP.NET applications)

Another approach will be create "lazy" loading method which return required list.

```
private static List<MyModel> MyModelInternal;
public static async Task<List<MyModel>> GetMyModelAsync()
{
    if (MyModelInternal == null)
    {
        MyModelInternal = await MyHelper.GetCacheAsync();
    }

    return Task.FromResult(MyModelInternal);
}
```

In case when internal list already initiated method will return complete task.

Or if you have some UI method where you can execute asynchronous method, then you can initialize your list there.